# Likelihood maximization between an outer product of a probability vector and a deterministic binary matrix

Tags: probability, optimization, maximum-likelihood, outer-product

We have a deterministic symmetric binary matrix (e.g., adjacency matrix) $A \in \{0, 1\}^{n \times n}$.
Given a vector $a \in [0, 1]^{n}$, we compute its outer product $\tilde{A} = a a^T \in [0, 1]^{n \times n}$, where $\tilde{A}_{ij} = a_i a_j$.
We see $\tilde{A}$ as a probability matrix and we aim to maximize the likelihood that $\tilde{A}$ takes the value of $A$, i.e., we aim to find
$$
\arg\max_{a \in [0, 1]^{n}} \prod_{i,j} \Pr[\operatorname{Bernoulli}(a_ia_j) = A_{ij}],
$$
where $\Pr[\operatorname{Bernoulli}(a_ia_j) = A_{ij}] = \tilde{A}_{ij} A_{ij} + (1 - \tilde{A}_{ij}) (1 - A_{ij})$.

Can we have a closed-form solution for the above optimization problem?

Comment: This is confusing. You write $A\in[0,1]^{n\times n}$, but you call $A$ a binary matrix, so presumably you mean $A\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$? But then I guess by "probability vector" you mean a vector of probabilities, so in that case presumably you do mean $[0,1]$ and not $\{0,1\}$? Also, the whole randomness aspect seems tangential to your actual question – isn't your question just how to find $a\in[0,1]$ so as to maximize $\prod_{i,j}a_ia_jA_{ij}+(1-a_ia_j)(1-A_{ij})$ for a given matrix $A$?

Comment: @joriki Thanks a lot for pointing out the problems in my question! I have corrected them and your final statement is definitely true, while I just wanted to provide some context of this question.

Comment: OK, thanks, you're right, providing context is good.